# Passing variable to a file name in a Remote PSSession

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass a variable to a file name but when the script finishes the file name is blank on the remote machine.

```
$serv = Read-host 'SERVER NAME'
$Session = New-PSSession -computername $serv 
Invoke-Command -session $session -ScriptBlock {
    reg export HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares C:\Users\admin\Desktop\$Serv.reg
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The easiest way would be to reference the variable with `$using:` => `$using:Serv`. The remote session can't see your local variable,